# Recommended path for storing files in Android that can be accessed by other apps and don't get removed upon uninstallation

Tags: android

I am builiding an Android application and have to create/read and write from multiple files for a feature.
The files need to persist even if I remove the application and the files should be browseable/accessible from other applications.
What is the recommened place to store such files and what permissions are needed for it ?

Comment: There is no recommended place as there is only one place for that: all public directories on external storage. Below Android 13 you need a write external storage permisdion.

Comment: But if you use SAF you can just let the user decide where to save files and do not need any permission.

Comment: @blackapps, If I need to write to the files in the backgrould. i.e, I create a file and write some data to it for some functionality without the user being aware of it As per my understanding , I can't use the SAF in this case . What should be done instead ?

Comment: I told you that in my first comment.

Comment: Thanks. You mentioned below Android 13 we need write external storage permission. What about Android 13 and above ?

Comment: Then you do not need that permission.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the recommened place to store such files

Store them where the user requests that you store them, using the Storage Access Framework (SAF), such as `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument`.

> what permissions are needed for it ?

No permissions are required to use the Storage Access Framework.

Comment: I can't ask the user to specify a location. I have to create this file for some internal purpose and write some data to it which I can later retrieve.